# Getting duplicate results with bridge table join

Tags: sql, postgresql

why in the world do I get duplicate of the same record with this query:

```
select
    lo.location_id,
    lo.name,
    lo.city_id,
    lo.state_id,
    lo. country_id
from location lo
join community_location cl on cl.community_id = 34
join location l on lo.location_id = cl.location_id
```

I end up having to put `distinct` on it to make sure I only get one of the same result.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do you mean by "duplicate"?

Comment: it's retrieving the same record over and over

Comment: provide your table structure, data and the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your original query:

```
select
    lo.location_id,
    lo.name,
    lo.city_id,
    lo.state_id,
    lo. country_id
from location lo
join community_location cl on cl.community_id = 34
join location l on lo.location_id = cl.location_id
```

You are joining to location twice.  The first time, you join all rows of location to the rows of community_location with I'd of 34.  This may only be one row.  However, you then join this result to all rows of location again, which is causing duplicates.  Here's how I think it should look:

```
select
    lo.location_id,
    lo.name,
    lo.city_id,
    lo.state_id,
    lo. country_id
from location lo
join community_location cl on lo.location_id = cl.location_id
where cl.community_id = 34 ;
```